# How to update a list of users in Firestore using Firebase admin sdk?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

So I'm learning how to use the firebase admin sdk and I've come across a problem that I'm not understanding enough to solve. Basically, I've queried my database and gotten a subset of users that I would like to update with the same value. So I stored the id's of each user that I want to update in an array, now I am trying to loop through that array and update each user. But I'm having a problem implementing this part and it has to do with the fact that .update() returns a promise and I'm not 100% how to handle this in a loop...

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp()
exports.getAllUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const db = admin.firestore()
  const users = db.collection('users').where('role', '==', 'artist').get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      //const users = querySnapshot.data()
      const promises = []
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc){
        promises.push(doc)
      })
      return Promise.all(promises) //returning promises sends the resolved results to 
    })                             //to the next .then()
    .then(function (person){
      let results = []
      person.forEach(function(personSnap){
        //const data = personSnap.data()
        results.push(personSnap.id)
      })
      return results  // results is the array of ids to update
    })
    //This .then() is where I have trouble understanding how to update
    .then(function (ids){
      for(var i = 0; i<ids.length; i++){
        var artistsRef = db.collection('users').doc(ids[i]);

        artistsRef.update({ //Should not be a return statement. This fixed my problem. Otherwise it would update the first user in the array and then leave the for loop.
          'free_credits': '2'
        })
      }
      return 'finished'
    })
    .then(function(reply) {
      return response.send(reply)
    })
    .catch(function (error){
      response.send(error)
    })

})
```

I feel like I should be returning 'artistsRef.update()' since it is a promise but I think that leads to unexpected results.

If I don't return the update() then ESLint throws the error: "Each then() should return a value or throw"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning early out of the final `then()` callback, before a response is sent.  Maybe you should add another `then()` just for sending the result after whatever final updates are complete.

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for the reply. I've actually been watching your Firebase cloud function videos to get a handle on how all of this works. So I got rid of the response in the .then() above (the one with the for loop) and instead called the response in a new .then() right after, but this resulted in an error in the .then() with the for loop. It still wants me to return something. So i returned null, but the function just times out when I run it. Could this be because I haven't set up a billing account with my project yet? This is just a simple database with 4 users in it...

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard for me to tell what's going on now, and it's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  It's not a billing problem.  If there was a billing problem, you wouldn't see any errors about promises.  If it's timing out, that means you're not sending a response.

Comment: So the end goal of this function is to update every 'artist' in my 'users' collection so that they have 2 free_credits. Basically my users get two free credits to spend each week, so at the start of each week I'll run this function so that they have credits to spend. It's going to be setup as a CRON job. I've edited the code above to show what I'm attempting now. It does actually return a response now, but only a single artist is updated instead of each one in the array. So I'm thinking the        **return artistsRef.update()** call is leaving the function prematurely

Comment: The response I'm getting is {"_writeTime":{"_seconds":1549312450,"_nanoseconds":297582000}}. I believe this is coming fro the update() function?

Comment: Yup, the problem was that I was **returning** the artistsRef.update() call which led to a premature exit of the .then() that was doing all of the update work. Getting rid of the return statement worked! Thanks for your help Doug!

Comment: Hey Doug, so I thought the function was working, and it did when I used it on a test database with only 4 users in it. But now that I'm trying it on an actually database with 400+ users I don't get an updates. Is there a limit on how many users I can update at a time?

Comment: Sounds like you have a new question to post on Stack Overflow. Be sure to include detailed observations.